# What is the proper way to include Typescript typings for js packages which will be published to npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, package, typescript-typings

I have 3 NodeJS packages, 2 of which will be published to npm later on and are in javascript, I want for them to have typings included with them. How do I do that properly?

I have one library `common`, one `user-facing` and a sample. Sample depends on `user-facing`, while that one depends on `common`.

I've created typings file for each .js file in each package, I included `"typings"` directive in `package.json` for each package specifying the main typing file.

But when I try to compile my sample `tsc` properly finds the typings for `user-facing` but then complains that it can't find further typings inside the files of `user-facing` which are trying to import `common`.

How can I run my sample locally without publishing the typings to registry beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to publish things to the typings registry for libraries that you create.  They can carry their own typings.  The typings registry is for creating typings for libraries that others created.

You want to include a typings element in the package.json

[Example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/package.json)

`"typings": "./yourentry.d.ts",`

And then have the build produce the typing .d.ts files

In your tsconfig:

`{
    "compilerOptions": {,
        "declaration": true,`

Doing that will allow tsc and vscode to find it and when consumers do an npm install, it will just work for compile time and intellisense.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. One more thing, is there a way to have the downloaded module's 3rd party typings downloaded when installing that npm module without explicitly stating them in the ```sample```'s typings.json?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had a typo in "typings" directive. Doing `npm link` to "instal" the depended packages was enough.